# help needed understaning ls format meaning

Tags: command-line, alias, ls, manpage

I hit `l` this evening while compiling some things, and got some unexpected output.

```
$ l
l3*  lesson03.cpp  lesson03.o  look.png  readme.txt
```

so then I looked at alias: which lists `l` as: `alias l='ls -F'`

So then I looked at the manpage, and still couldn't figure out the meaning of `ls -F`

```
-F, --classify
          append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

Can someone explain the meaning of the as-tricks next to some files,? what is being said in "*/=>@|" ? I don't get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`info ls`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html#General-output-formatting):

```
‘-F’
‘--classify’
‘--indicator-style=classify’
     Append a character to each file name indicating the file type.
     Also, for regular files that are executable, append ‘*’.  The file
     type indicators are ‘/’ for directories, ‘@’ for symbolic links,
     ‘|’ for FIFOs, ‘=’ for sockets, ‘>’ for doors, and nothing for
     regular files.  Do not follow symbolic links listed on the command
     line unless the ‘--dereference-command-line’ (‘-H’),
     ‘--dereference’ (‘-L’), or
     ‘--dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir’ options are specified.
```